# 2013 Toyota Tacoma flashing 4x4 light on dash

Tags: toyota, 4wd, tacoma

My friends Tacoma has the flashing green 4x4 light going on the dash.  I read the instructions regarding putting it into 4 wheel drive, 2 wheel drive and 4x4 low and nothing changed. We drove it to an auto zone and the guy hooked up the scanner and said no codes.

Any advice on what we can do next?

Edit:
The 4x4 light is supposed to stay on green.  I had not used it in 3 months.  When I started the car in the morning it was flashing green for no apparent reason.  No codes from a scan have shown up.

*please, if someone tells me to take it to the dealership, I'm gonna freak out.  I already know we can do that    :-)

Comment: Do you know what the green light means?  Green doesn't sound like a fault warning.

Comment: Agree with @HandyHowie, if it's anything like the '08 Pathfinder we used to own then it just means that 4x4 mode has been engaged but it's waiting for the right conditions to engage all four wheels. Those "right" conditions should be in the manual. Could you post them up here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, it was a vacuum line for me. I found the leak, fixed it and the light no longer blinks. So check out your vacuum line for leaks.

Comment: Do you have any information regarding which vacuum line?

Comment: My leak was coming from a cracked line near the actuator. Mine was underneath the battery tray.

Comment: Same thing happened to mine.  Vacuum leak.

Comment: You were right.  Exactly right!

Answer (score 8):

On [page 186 of the owners manual](http://www.toyota.com/t3Portal/document/om/OM35A10U/pdf/sec_2-4.pdf) there are instructions that tell you what to do when this indicator blinks.  Highlighted below:

[image]

<sup>(highlight added for emphasis)</sup>

Given that you've tried shifting to different modes several times, you may not know what mode it thinks it's shifting from.  You may be able to simply go through all the possible sequences described above.

If you go through all the possible sequences above and it's still blinking, the dealership or a suitable mechanic may be your only resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving the switch in fourwheel drive turn off engine, restart and light may remain solid green and should be engaged in 4x4. Turn off switch and the drive should disconnect and light goes off like it should at least that's how my 2014 reacted to that remedy.prior to that I drove 60 miles with the light blinking and no 4x4.

Comment: Wayne's fix worked perfectly for mine. I was driving in some snow with H4 on, when I went to switch back to H2, the light remained blinking. Tried swapping modes in park, in drive, and in neutral. Turning it off in H4 then back on resulted in a steady light, which went out normally upon switching to H2. Thanks!